# Calculate execution time of one or more lines of code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there a way (a class-made in C #) that would allow me to calculate the time required to execute some lines in my program.

Ex :

```
try
{
  string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    conn.Open();

    ***// start counting: 
    // time = 0*** 

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
     “SELECT * FROM Books”, conn))
      using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
         while (reader.Read())
          {
             Console.WriteLine(“{0}\t{1}\t{2}”, 
             reader.GetInt32(0),
             reader.GetString(1), 
             reader.GetInt32(2));
          }

   ***// end counting 
   // time = 10 sec***
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use the built-in [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// do something

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0} milliseconds", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [System.Diagnostics.StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to do it manually or consider using a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
static TimeSpan Time(Action action) {
  var sw = StopWatch.StartNew();
  action();
  sw.Stop();
  return sw.Elapsed
}
```

Then you can just do

var time=Time(() => { // MyCode here });

Comment: This would work but it would have around 15-16 milliseconds precision since DateTime.Now jumps values in about that amount of ms.